# Does inflation should occur in output layer when I do Artificial Neural Network to increase smartness of the model?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The idea that come to my mind is called Value Based Model for ANN. We use simple DCF formula to calculate kind of Q value: Rewards/Discount rate. Discount rate is a risk of getting the reward on the information that agent know about. Of course if you have many factors you just sum that. So, we calculate FV for every cell that agent know information about and this is a predicted data. We put predicted - actual and teach model how to run using loss function. Rephrased, does increase in output layer actually train the model to be better? The human logic is that if I took course I have a bigger value that helps me to live. What about NN? Does it actually more precise if we with time increase output?